# Screen Hangs randomly on Monitor

Tags: display, graphics-card, freeze, bsod, memtest86+

My Monitor screen hangs randomly, below are some instances:-

1. Hanged while in boot menu itself.
2. Hanged while running Memtest86+ using bootable USB.
3. Hanged while running OS.

case 1,2 shows it should NOT be driver or software problem as they come into picture after OS loads, and my screen hanged before that.

Memtest ran successfully 4th time i tried, it ran it for 6 hours doing 4 passes without any errors, so this should mean my RAM is OK.

I have inbuilt graphics memory only, so i tried testing it by opening dozens of chrome tabs many with youtube HD videos, video in vlc, Eclipse, and other applications. In this case CPU usage reached 100% many times but physical memory never crossed 93%, even though video showed lags,etc but , screen did not Hanged at all. So, i closed all of them and when i was about to shutdown PC, it hanged again.

I have tried reconnecting my Monitor cables properly and now i feel that frequency of issue has come down(may be i am wrong here),but not come to 0.

So, My question is what exactly is issue with my PC hardware, and why problem surfaces in LESS stress on graphics rather than more stress?